# Events fired from a GWT Frame

Tags: javascript, gwt

I would like to know whether how events from a `GWT Frame` is fired. I mean, for example HTTP events, if I use some debugging tool, would I see that HTTP events coming from the underlying `Iframe` element.

For example the loaded page in the `iframe` contains image urls, would I see `GET` request to image coming from the Iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on tool you are using. Chrome console always shows what was cause for an event (e.g. javascript in iframe). Some proxy servers  (like Fiddler2) will be able to display only referrer header (which will be an address of page where iframe is included)

Comment: I actually want to implement it through GWT module or any javascript.

Comment: Oops,so you want something different. I suggest you mention it explicitly in a question.